# what is the difference between rowid and rownum in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

Does **oracle** make a distinction between rowid and rownum?

If so what is the **differnce**?

Answer (score 1):

You can see this great [explanation](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rownum_rowid_difference.htm) .

To summarize rowid is a permanent identifier of your row.

The rownum is pseudo column that is varying with each query.

So to get for example the first 1000 records you can do:

```
select * from Table where rownum <= 1000
```